# Swedish Characters Not showing properly after sending xml message on a topic (Java-8)

Tags: character-encoding, java-8

There a tag in which i must set the string "Vänligen Klicka på länken". 
But its showing different characters in place of all of 'ä' and 'å'. Everything else works fine except this XML tag output is different.

```
    String linkMsg = "Vänligen Klicka på länken";
    byte[] bytes = linkMsg .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String newString = new String(bytes,"UTF-8");
    LinkField linkField = new LinkField();
    linkField.setStringValue(newString);
```

The output i get is "VÃ¤nligen Klicka pÃ¥ lÃ¤nken".

Part of Maven pom,

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>se.link.Application</start-class>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

I am Using Spring Boot.

Comment: This could be due to a number of things. Have you done any diagnostics yourself?

Comment: All other stuff works fine and message also send fine. But this string shows up different. I tried Converting to other formats, but doesnot work. I have not done any other test as i dont know any other methods.

Comment: Start by checking the actual encoding of the response. Make sure there are no conflicting statements on what the encoding actually is, i.e. check the http response headers, check the actual response contents and of course check the contents of the markup.

Comment: In the XML message the encoding is mentioned "UTF-8" and this is also converted to UTF-8...still it doesnot work

Comment: How about the response headers and the actual content?  Just stating it is utf-8 doesn't necessarily make it so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`linkMsg.getBytes()` gives you the string encoded in the platform default character set - which is probably not UTF-8. You are then treating this as though it was UTF-8.

Use `linkMsg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` to get the string bytes encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: Updated Question. Did like that but same output. Am i missing something here.